# Knowing how to time a task when building a progress bar

Tags: python, progress-bar

In my program a user uploads a csv file.
While the file is uploading & being processed by my app, I'd like to show a progress bar.

The problem is that this process isn't entirely under my control (I can't really tell how long it'll take for the file to finish loading & be processed, as this depends on the file content and the size).

What would be the correct approach for doing this? It's not like I have many steps and I could increment the progress bar every time a step happens.... It's basically waiting for a file to be loaded, I cannot determine the time for that!

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at Python-progressbar? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give much detail, so I'll explain what I think is happening and give some suggestions from my thought process.

> You have some kind of app that has some kind of function/process that
>   is a black-box (i.e you can't see inside it or change it), this
>   black-box uploads a csv file to some server and returns control back to
>   your app when it's done. Since you can't see inside the black-box you
>   can't determine how much it has uploaded and thus can't create an
>   accurate progress bar.

**Named Pipes**:
If you're passing only the filename of the csv to the black-box, you might be able to create a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) (depending on your situation.) Since named pipes block after the buffer is full - until the receiver reads it, you could keep track of how much has been read and thus create an accurate progress bar.

*So you would create a named pipe, pass the black-box its filename, and then read in from the csv - and write to the named pipe. How far you've read in - is your progress.*

**More Pythonic**:
Since you tagged Python, if you're passing the csv as a file-like object, this [activestate recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578669-wrap-a-string-in-a-file-like-object-that-calls-a-u/) could help.
Same kind of idea just for Python.

**Conclusion**: These are two possible solutions. I'm getting tired, and there may be many more - but I can't help more since you haven't given us much to work with.

To answer your question at an *abstract level:* you can't make accurate progress bars for black-box functions, after all they could have a **sleep(random())** call in them for all you know.

There are ways around this that are implementation specific, the two ideas above are examples: the idea being you can make the black-box take a stream instead, and count the bytes as you pass them through.

Alternatively you can guess/approximate, a rough calculation of how many bytes are going in and a (previously calculated) average speed per byte would give you *some* kind of indication of when it would complete. You could even save how long each run took in your code and do the previous idea automatically getting better each time.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, so you guessed correctly :) Great, I'll look into both options but I think I have a general idea of what to do. Thanks